# Cannot get nested value in readonly object

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a type called ParamsArr which is defined below.

```
type BoolParamObj = {
    name: string,
    type: "boolean",
    default?: boolean
}
type BoolParam = string | BoolParamObj

type EnumParam = {
    name: string,
    type: "enum",
    values: readonly string[]
}

type ParamTypes = BoolParam | EnumParam

type ParamsArr = ReadonlyArray<ParamTypes>
```

I want to create a union containing all strings and object name properties. For some reason, I cannot get them.

```
type KeysFromParams<P extends ParamsArr> =
    P[number] extends BoolParamObj | EnumParam ?
    P[number]["name"] :
    P[number]


const params = [
    "hello",
    {
        name: "world",
        type: "boolean"
    } as const satisfies BoolParamObj
] as const satisfies ParamsArr


let key = "world" satisfies KeysFromParams<typeof params> //somehow this is an object?
```

Why is it saying that "world" should be an object and not the string "world"?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
type KeysFromParams<P extends ParamsArr> = {
    [key in keyof P]:
    P[key] extends BoolParamObj | EnumParam ?
    P[key]["name"]:
    P[key]
}[number]
```